# Definition of Borel regular outer measure.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, outer-measure, borel-measures

I have ran across this in the hypothesis of one certain theorem.

Let $X$  be a separable metric space with a Borel regular outer measure $\mu^{*}$ such that $\mu^{*}X = 1 $.

I don't understand the essence of this. what does it mean that a separable metric space is endowed with a boreal regular outer measure $\mu^{*}$ such that $\mu^{*}X = 1 $ ?

How is metric defined there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Definition of an outer measure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure Definition of a regular measure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure

Comment: @BBBBBB yes I’ve read these definitions but the thing that I can not understand is, what happens to measure $\mu$ in this space? Not an outer measure.

Comment: It really is not clear what your question is

Comment: @Andrew https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure is this the definition of regular outer measure? And how the metric is defined there?

Comment: @JohnNash You do not need a metric to talk about Borel measures or Borel regular measures.  They make sense in a general topological space.

Comment: @MW but we have separable metric space there.

Comment: @JohnNash  So what is the problem?  You have a separable metric, it has a topology.  I don't understand the question I'm afraid.

Comment: @MW how should i define the distance function which is characteristic for Metric space.

Comment: @MW https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4773827/measure-preserving-transformation-from-separable-metric-space-into-an-interval Check this one, I would be very grateful.