# Measure-preserving transformation from separable metric space into an interval $[0;1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Let $X$  be a separable metric space with a Borel regular outer measure $\mu^{*}$ such that $\mu^{*}X = 1 $.

I want to prove  that  there exists a measure preserving transformation $f : X \to [0;1]$ such that for every Open ball $B$ in $X$, there exists a subball $B^{*}$ such that $\mu(B^{*}) = m(f(B^{*}))$, where $m$ is Lebesgue-measure.

I have really a trouble in constructing such mapping, I think it will be  enough too  if I just show that such mapping exists, without constructing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you prove in mathematics that something exists without constructing it?

Comment: @LeeMosher there could be some occasions. I have just said that it would be good without constructing too, but if there is way to construct, it would be even better and I would be very grateful.

Comment: @JohnNash. Just for clarification, what is your definition of a “measure preserving transformation”?  Usually I see that term used for a self-map $f\colon X\to X$, and it’s defined by the condition $f_*\mu=\mu$, I.e $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$.  But here $f$ is between different spaces.  When you say “$f$ is measure preserving” did you perhaps mean 1. $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=m(A)$ for all $A$?  Or 2. $f$ is measurable? Or 3. Something else?

Comment: @LeeMosher Not every proof is constructive.

Comment: If $X$ is also complete  and $\mu$ has no atoms, then isomorphism theorem of measure theory answers your question.

Comment: Some proofs cite existence axioms such as the completeness axioms, yes... and existence theorems may cite other existence theorems and so on... but in the end, many many existence theorems are constructive.

Comment: @MW Yes, I mean exactly that. The first one.

Comment: @geetha290krm We don’t know if $X$ is complete and $\mu$ is non-atomic or not.

Comment: @geetha290krm All separable nonatomic normalized measure algebras are mutually isomorphic. This is the theorem you have mentioned. My measure algebra is normalized, but I don’t know if it is atomic.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you give me a link of this theorem? I would be grateful.

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Measure_algebra_(measure_theory)

Comment: @geetha290krm can you tell me how is Boolean algebra is defined and isomorphism? I also would love to see the proof of this theorem, or official source. I have to use it in artcile. I would be grateful if you help me.

Comment: I mean why is isomorphism and measure-preserving mapping the same

Comment: Does measure-preserving follow from isomorphism between two spaces?